# Joomla 1.7 Mail settings configuration

Tags: joomla1.7

Can anyone suggest any helpful reading text on configuring mail settings on joomla 1.7 .

I have read the [joomla docs](http://docs.joomla.org/Global_configuration) however i am facing errors like :

on sendmail : Could not execute: /var/qmail/bin/sendmail

on smtp : SMTP Error! Could not connect to SMTP host

maybe a little help with some setting suggestions will do the trick.
Thank you.

Comment: Ive resolved this issue by creating a contact profile and adding the corresponding email settings to the sendmail panel ..

Comment: What host do you use?  On ipage I had no problems but I recently switched to hostgator and now my site admins don't get any mail.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your hosting provider needs Authorization for the SMTP. I would suggest SMTP, its less "Spamy" for mailservers because it sends out the right headers.

1. Create a new email just for this website.
2. Put your Username and Password  in the configuration of Joomla
3. Try to use the port 587 instead of 25 in case you can't connect. Many providers use this port